# Automation of a Angular ApplicationUI using selenium

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, selenium-webdriver

my next project is a pure angular application.my first task is to automate the UI after that the other testings comes.. and my question is that can we use selenium for UI automating a angular application and if so how can we do that .. if any references please let me know that..please help me by posting your valuable comments .. thanks in advance

Comment: If it is angular application, Go for Protractor 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/

Comment: ok.. let me try protractor..thanks for the suggetion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) provides various element selectors with web driver for all browsers.

So as you are starting with new project, I will suggest you try adding unique and precise ids to elements which will help while writing automation scripts.

There are other frameworks too which are designed to target anguar app automation testing like [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/).

As angular have limited support for IE at some point you might get stucked with selenium where protractor will make your life easy.

Comment: ok.. i'll try Protractor ..thank you

Comment: can we use eclipse ide to write test cases ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code you can use fro protractor.

Comment: @Neethu yes, eclipse will be good option